# New secret achievements in RETRY

Tags: ios, retry

The latest version (1.5.0) released last week added a few achievements, "Shoe Size: Monster", "Cryptozoology Breakthrough", "Mechanical Rowboat", "That About Wraps It Up" and "Meow Meow Meow!". They're intended to be secret, since there's no indication how to unlock them at all, except very, very vague hints about where you're likely to find them.

I only managed to unlock the last one because it's obvious to those who finished the game. But what about the others? How to unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll just list all the new secret achievements.

**Summer, Shoe Size: Monster** (originally posted by [andbeyond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/96595/andbeyond))

> On W1's level **28: Moving Around**, fly to the 5th Retry Point. It should be nested in a little cave in which you flip into. There will be a bulldozer above you and a bush below you. If you sit on the retry point for a short while, Bigfoot will start waving at you from the bush. You will earn the achievement without needing to tap anything.

**Winter, Cryptozoology Breakthrough**

> On W1's level **32: Flying High**, go to the 3rd Retry Point, where there is a snowy platform with a gray rock below the runway. Just wait a while and a yeti will come out and wave. You will earn the achievement without needing to tap anything.

**Future, Mechanical Rowboat**

> On W1's level **38: Clockworks**, go to the 4th Retry Point, which is right after the slow-motion section with the three rotating plus-signs. There is a platform in the shape of a small boat below the runway, casting a shadow. Wait until a blue robot comes out of it and waves. You will earn the achievement without needing to tap anything.

**Pyramids, That About Wraps It Up**

> On W1's level **55: Deep Dive**, go to the 5th Retry Point. A platform with a bush should be visible below the runway. Wait until a mummy comes out and waves. You will earn the achievement without needing to tap anything.

**Cat, Meow Meow Meow!**

> Tap the cat that shows up after beating W1's B11

Comment: Thanks. And found the Pyramid secret too - Level 55, last retry point.